# F# define search function

Tags: recursion, search, functional-programming, f#, boolean

I am new to F# and am having trouble with my code. Its a simple problem to define a function, search, with that take a boolean function and a list and return an index. So for example:

```
> search (fun x -> x > 10) [ 2; 12; 3; 23; 62; 8; 2 ];;
val it : int = 1

> search (fun s -> s < "horse") [ "pig"; "lion"; "horse"; "cow"; "turkey" ];;
val it : int = 3
```

What I have as of right now finds the right match but what I cant figure out is how to return a number instead of the rest of the list. I know I'm getting the list instead of a value back because I wrote "if f head then list". What I don't know is what I should put there instead or if what I have is not going to get the result I want.

Below is the code I have written.

```
let rec search f list =
    match list with
        | [] -> [-1]
        | head::tail ->
            if f head then list
            else search f tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning a number is easy, you just... return it. Your problem is that you don't *have* a number to return, because you can't derive it directly from the current state. You have to keep track of the number yourself, using some internal state variable.

When using recursion you change state by calling your function recursively with "modified" arguments. You're already doing that with the list here. To keep internal state in a recursive function you have to introduce another argument, but not expose it outside. You can solve that by using an internal recursive helper function. Here's one that keeps track of the previous item and returns that when it encounters a match:

```
let search f list =
    let rec loop list prev =
        match list with
            | [] -> None
            | head::tail ->
                if f head then prev
                else loop tail (Some head)
    in
    loop list None
```

That's a silly example, but I don't want to just solve your homework for you, because then you wouldn't learn anything. Using this you should be able to figure out how to keep a counter of which position the current item is in, and return that when it matches. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You typically define an inner recursive function to help you carry state as you loop, and then call the inner function with an initial state.

```
   let search predicate list =
    let rec loop list index =
        match list with
            | [] -> -1
            | head::tail ->
                if predicate head then index
                else loop tail (index + 1)
    loop list 0
```